# How do you shoot black product images?

Tags: studio-lighting, studio, studio-setup

I'm a 3D Artist currently struggling at "shooting" product photos of black objects with black backgrounds. Does anybody have clues about the studio setup used in the references below? Did they use indirect softboxes?
I figured out to post the question here as i'm using a physical-based rendering engine.

Reference photography: [http://imgur.com/a/qi4sT](https://imgur.com/a/qi4sT)

Comment: The images look like they could be computer rendered. Curious why you think they were shot through a lens with a camera.

Comment: ben rudgers thank you for your reply. I thought they were photographs because of the little imperfections you may notice in the business cards (at the angle for example, or even slightly the holes). Here is another remarkable example: https://www.behance.net/gallery/33283887/View-From-A-Blue-Moon-Book; On the other  hand , as i am not photographer, what made you think the pictures were rendered?

Comment: good lighting and good post-processing ?

Comment: I hadn't thought about it until just now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second photo you will notice that the light on the bench top falls away gradually, from left to right. That is, the left side of the bench is brighter than the right. Likewise, the shadow behind the right-most card suggests a single light source to the left of frame.

The shadow does not have clearly defined edges. That is, it is "soft" - therefore I would suggest a large softbox was probably used.

In the first photo, the height of the shadow is perhaps 60% of the height of the box - this should give you a clue as to how high the softbox was positioned - above the camera, but not too high, otherwise your shadow would be quite low in the shot.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed and rich answer youcantryreachingme, i'll try to reproduce the lighting setup you pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

About the 'Black books'. Apart from the light setup and all, I believe a polarizing filter was used on the lens in order to remove even small reflections from the lettering on the back of the books.

Comment: I'd have never thought of that, thank you vkjaersgaard